# Paramiko stdout to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a paramiko sdout output in a table format as below:

```
opt = sddout.read().decode('ascii')
**********
*  Name  *
**********
Port Vlan Name
Gi1  001  Test1
G12  002  Test2
Gi3  003  Test3
```

I need to convert this output to pandas dataframe by removing the the star(*) and data inside the stars(*).

I tried the following ways but its not working as expected.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
opt = sddout.read().decode('ascii')
opt = StringIO(opt)
df = pd.read_csv(opt, sep="\n")
```

The above script is not giving the output in expected format.

```
Expected output:
print(df)
    Port Vlan Name
    Gi1  001  Test1
    G12  002  Test2
    Gi3  003  Test3

Print(df['Port'])
    Port 
    Gi1  
    G12  
    Gi3  
Print(df['Vlan'])
    Vlan
    001
    002
    003
```

Please help me out with any suggestions

Comment: You can try  skip the first 3 rows: `pd.read_csv(opt, skiprows=3, sep="\n")`

Comment: @Psidom. You can use `comment='*'` instead of `skiprows=3`

Comment: @Corralien Yeah, good point. Upvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
opt = io.StringIO(opt)
df = pd.read_table(opt, sep='\s+', comment='*')
print(df)

# Output
  Port  Vlan   Name
0  Gi1     1  Test1
1  G12     2  Test2
2  Gi3     3  Test3
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem?